# com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath cannot find key

Tags: json

I am trying to use **com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath** to read key/values from a JSON string:

```
String contentAsString = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
System.out.println(contentAsString);
Object value = JsonPath.read(contentAsString, "$.key");
```

But I get the error:

```
Expected to find an object with property ['key'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
```

Printing `contentAsString`  gives:

```
[{"firstName":"N","key":"mykey"}]
```

Is `contentAsString`  not valid JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blob that you posted *is not* a valid **JSON Object**, however, it IS a valid **JSON Array**.

To read this using JsonPath, try using this:

```
Object value = JsonPath.read(contentAsString, "$[0].key");
```

This will get the value of the `key` object, from the 0th element of the initial array.